# combineLatest in Angular 7 not executing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

```
combineLatest(this.route.params, this.campaignService.count()).pipe(flatMap(result => {

  console.log('combinelatest');
  const params = result[0];

  this.count = result[1];

  if (params['page']) {
    this.page = params['page'];
  }
  this.offset = (this.page - 1) * this.limit;

  return this.campaignService.list(this.offset);
})).subscribe(json => {
  this.campaignList = json;
}, error => {
  let message;
  if (error.status === 401) {
    message = 'Unauthorized';
  } else if (error.status === 500) {
    message = 'Internal server error';
  } else if (error.status === 400) {
    message = 'Bad request';
  }

  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(GeneralModalComponent);
  modalRef.componentInstance.modalTitle = 'Error';
  modalRef.componentInstance.modalMessage = message;
});
```

So I'm using Angular 7's combineLatest to use flatMap to chain to call an API, but it doesn't seem like the code is executing. What do you think that I missed out in this code snippet? I was modifying it from Angular 6. The previous Observable.combineLatest, flatMap, then subscribe worked.

Comment: Are you sure that `this.route.params` and `this.campaignService.count()` emit a value?

Comment: The problem as fridoo is saying must come from one of those. You subscribed correctly, and if you never get in the callback then the emitters do not do what they are expected to do.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks for the pointers.